# Python keeps showing 'object has no such attribute'

Tags: python, tkinter, compiler-errors

for some reason when executing the following lines of code, there is an error stating: **'car' object has no attribute 'time_int'** The class is called car.

Although I have included the methods in the same class, every time I try to call `self.time_int` there is the error above, here is the code fragment:

```
# the __init__ also has the buttons that connect to other methods, but I just included the relevant one

    class car:


    def __init__(self,master):

        self.helv = tkinter.font.Font(family ="Helvetica", size = 20, weight = 'bold')

        self.master = master

        master.title('RC car controls')
        self.background_image = PhotoImage(file='1.gif') #upload background picture
        self.background_label = Label(master, image=self.background_image)
        self.background_label.image = self.background_image
        self.background_label.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1, relheight=1) #placing of background picture
        master.geometry("500x500")
        master.resizable(0, 0)

        self.acl = Button(master, command = lambda:    [self.set_down(),self.set_up()], image = self.img,
                      padx = 4, pady = 4)
        self.acl.place(relx = 0.7, rely = 0.5)


    def set_down(self):
        self.acl.bind('<Button-1>', self.accel_gn)


    def set_up(self):
        self.acl.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',self.accel_fn)

    def accel_fn(self,accel_fn):  ##### ACCELERATION SLOWS DOWN
        self.start = time()
        print('up')
        self.time_int = (self.start-self.end)
        print(self.time_int)

    def accel_gn(self,accel_gn): ##### ACCELERATION INCREASES
        self.end = time()
        a = speed()
        print('down')
        if 1 > self.time_int > 0:
            print('current motor speed:', a.final_speed())
```

The error occurs in the second method `accel_gn(self,accel_gn)` on the line of the if statment. To clarify, the button basically checks how long the it's pressed down and calls a method in another class called final_speed().

Thanks

EDIT: when I press the button the second time in the idle, it just continues to run and the error doesn't stop it. The error only pops up the first time the button is clicked.

Comment: could you post the implementation of `__init__` method of this class?

Comment: In fact, the complete definition would be ideal--you can edit your question to create a [mcve] that shows the problem in action.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define `self.time_int` in `accel_gn`

Comment: define it with the same value as the one in ```accel_fn``` or with something else?

Comment: the same value.

Comment: Ok just tried it, defining it as ```self.time_int = (self.start-self.end)```  it now gives me the error: AttributeError: 'car' object has no attribute 'start'

Comment: yes, because `start` is inside the other function --`accel_fn`. You will have to access that information from there